# update Binary field in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a string which is an encrypted binary value

```
(0x00C11EA094DC7F45AD2B13F42E26ED03010000006018F6DFCEC8BAFC47AC2854C21A5B00FEFA7C3035A9A4EF7AEBB9FDADBF7FA4B2E6392EA0DC4614).
```

I need to pass the exact above string to a `VarBinary` column in SQL Server from .net.

How can I do this?

Regards
Rajeesh

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
        var input = "your value string";
        var connectionString = "";

        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
           connection.Open();
           using(var command = new SqlCommand("your query : stored procedure", connection))
           {
             command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

             // your parameter in your stored procedure
             SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@parameter", SqlDbType.VarBinary); 
             parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter.Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);

             command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
         }
```

Comment: Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input) will give us a new binary string and not the one i have in the input variable.... Are u getting my point?